# Can browse ftp.microsoft.com but not our own FTP site in IE

Tags: firewall, iis-7, ftp, microsoft-ftmg-2010

We want to have an FTP site that works the same way ftp://ftp.microsoft.com works.  We want to be able to browse the FTP site in web browsers.

It seems that just recently, users are unable to browse our anonymous FTP site in IE.  It works in Chrome.  It works 'partially' in Firefox in that they can access the folders but cannot see the files.

If we go to our site in IE, we get "This page cannot be displayed", yet I am able to browse ftp://ftp.microsoft.com in IE without changing any browser settings.

The FTP site in IIS7 is set to Anonymous Access, with Read selected.  I'm wondering what else might need to be done on the server to get this functionality.

**Edit:**

After some discussion below, we are wondering if it could be a firewall set to block FTP traffic in web browsers, however I am not familiar with such a setting in TMG.

Comment: Have you checked NTFS permissions ?

Comment: Every user listed has at least Read permissions.

Comment: Beside that, it is very very strange that it works with Chrome, partially with FF, and not with IE......is your ftp public ? if yes is a temporary account access is possible to figure out the problem ?

Comment: We do have another account setup which has write permissions.  Would that help diagnose?  It works fine using SmartFtp too.

Comment: I just want to reproduce different browser behaviour on my computer because i am baffled...

Comment: I can send you the ip address if you'd like.  Yeah we think it's baffling too, maybe a routing issue.

Comment: yes i would like the ip address

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11849/discussion-between-david-and-user2196728)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering tests we have done, i think there is a firewall that acts at application layer.
I think they want to block FTP traffic coming from browser to only allow real FTP client (Filezilla and others).
If it works fine with Chrome i think it is because Chrome acts more as a FTP client when url is ftp:// contrary to other browser.

Comment: I looked at our firewall and couldn't find anything out of the ordinary.  We actually have another non-MS FTP server that works fine.  Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: hmmm i'm going to capture network traffic against your server...i cannot believe that different browser behaviour can be du to the fact that your actaul FTP server is Microsoft based

Comment: Ok, we have a consultant who specializes in the firewall and it turns out he did in fact make some kind of change, possible on the router, that caused this strange issue.  I'm not sure of the details, but sounds like you were right.